# Filtering a Pyspark DataFrame with SQL-like IN clause

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I want to filter a Pyspark DataFrame with a SQL-like `IN` clause, as in

```
sc = SparkContext()
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlc.sql('SELECT * from my_df WHERE field1 IN a')
```

where `a` is the tuple `(1, 2, 3)`. I am getting this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.67] failure: ``('' expected but identifier a found

which is basically saying it was expecting something like *'(1, 2, 3)'* instead of a.
The problem is I can't manually write the values in a as it's extracted from another job.

How would I filter in this case?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

String you pass to `SQLContext` it evaluated in the scope of the SQL environment. It doesn't capture the closure. If you want to pass a variable you'll have to do it explicitly using string formatting:

```
df = sc.parallelize([(1, "foo"), (2, "x"), (3, "bar")]).toDF(("k", "v"))
df.registerTempTable("df")
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM df WHERE v IN {0}".format(("foo", "bar"))).count()
##  2
```

Obviously this is not something you would use in a "real" SQL environment due to security considerations but it shouldn't matter here.

In practice `DataFrame` DSL is a much better choice when you want to create dynamic queries:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.where(col("v").isin({"foo", "bar"})).count()
## 2
```

It is easy to build and compose and handles all details of HiveQL / Spark SQL for you.

Comment: For the second method, you can achieve the same by doing df.where(df.v.isin({"foo", "bar"})).count()

Comment: You can, but personally I don't like this approach. With `col` I can easily decouple SQL expression and particular `DataFrame` object. So you can for example keep a dictionary of useful expressions and just pick them when you need. With explicit DF object you'll have to put it inside a function and it doesn't compose that well.

Comment: How can this be done with a list of tuples? If I have e.g. `[(1,1), (1,2), (1,3)]` where one is `aid` and the other is `bid` for example. It would have to be something like `col(['aid', 'bid]).isin([(1,1), (1,2)])`

Answer (score 36):

reiterating what @zero323 has mentioned above : we can do the same thing using a **list as well (not only `set`)** like below

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.where(col("v").isin(["foo", "bar"])).count()
```

Comment: @zero323 is there a negation of is in LIKE not in sparksql.

Comment: Yes. You can use '~'

Answer (score 11):

Just a little addition/update:

```
choice_list = ["foo", "bar", "jack", "joan"]
```

If you want to filter your dataframe "df", such that you want to keep rows based upon a column "v" taking only the values from choice_list, then

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df_filtered = df.where( ( col("v").isin (choice_list) ) )
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also do this for integer columns:

```
df_filtered = df.filter("field1 in (1,2,3)")
```

or this for string columns:

```
df_filtered = df.filter("field1 in ('a','b','c')")
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach that worked for me is to filter with a custom filter function.

```
def filter_func(a):
"""wrapper function to pass a in udf"""
    def filter_func_(col):
    """filtering function"""
        if col in a.value:
            return True

    return False

return udf(filter_func_, BooleanType())

# Broadcasting allows to pass large variables efficiently
a = sc.broadcast((1, 2, 3))
df = my_df.filter(filter_func(a)(col('field1'))) \
```

Answer (score 0):

```python
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('Practise').getOrCreate()
df_pyspark=spark.read.csv('datasets/myData.csv',header=True,inferSchema=True)
df_spark.createOrReplaceTempView("df") # we need to create a Temp table first
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM df where Departments in ('IOT','Big Data') order by Departments").show()
```