# SQL like NOT IN clause for PySpark data frames

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In SQL, we can for example, do `select * from table where col1 not in ('A','B');`

I was wondering if there is a PySpark equivalent for this. I was able to find the `isin` function for SQL like `IN` clause, but nothing for `NOT IN`.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870760/filtering-a-pyspark-dataframe-with-sql-like-in-clause

Comment: `foo NOT IN ('a', 'b') == NOT (foo IN ('a', 'b'))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just had the same issue and found solution. If you want to negate any condition (in pySpark represented as `Column` class) there is negation operator `~`, for example:

```
df.where(~df.flag.isin(1, 2, 3)) # records with flag NOT IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to call the `isin()` method from `F.col()` like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.filter(~F.col("col1").isin('A','B'))
```

Giving access to the '`isin`' documentation within your IDE (of course if you are using [PySpark-Stubs](https://pypi.org/project/pyspark-stubs/)).

Comment: Why do you prefer this approach over the one proposed in the accepted answer? Are there specific scenarios where this might work better?

Comment: probably I might add it in the answer but yes, I prefer this method of the column object as is possible to access library methods and documentation differently by calling the df field (namely df.flag) which doesn't provide access to isin documentation for example

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
df = df.filter(df.sbg_digitalId.isin(1, 2, 3) == False)
```