# Pyspark: multiple filter on string column

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Assume the below table is pyspark dataframe and I want to apply filter on a column *ind* on multiple values. How to perform this in pyspark?

```
ind group people value 
John  1    5    100   
Ram   1    2    2       
John  1    10   80    
Tom   2    20   40    
Tom   1    7    10    
Anil  2    23   30
```

I am trying following, but without success

```
filter = ['John', 'Ram']
filtered_df = df.filter("ind == filter ")
filtered_df.show()
```

How to achieve this in spark?

Comment: This does the reverse of what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39624277/sql-like-not-in-clause-for-pyspark-data-frames - so you know that you need to use the `in` function/operator.

Comment: Here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyspark isin function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44444632/pyspark-isin-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
filter = ['John', 'Ram']
filtered_df = df.filter("ind in ('John', 'Ram') ")
filtered_df.show()
```

Or

```
filter = ['John', 'Ram']
processed_for_pyspark = ', '.join(['\'' + s + '\'' for s in filter])
filtered_df = df.filter("ind in ({}) ".format(processed_for_puspark))
filtered_df.show()
```

if you want to have your filters in a list. Also note that we use the single equal `=` instead of the double equal `==` to test equality in pyspark (like in SQL)

Answer (score 3):

you could use the built in function isin:
`filtered_df = df.filter(df["ind"].isin(["John", "Ram"])`