# Pyspark: filter DataaFrame where column value equals some value in list of Row objects

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list of `pyspark.sql.Row` objects as follows:

```
[Row(artist=1255340), Row(artist=942), Row(artist=378), Row(artist=1180), Row(artist=813)]
```

From a `DataFrame` having schema `(id, name)` I want to `filter` out rows where `id equals some artist in the given Row of list`. What will be the correct way to go about it ?

To clarify further, I want to do something like: `select row from dataframe where row.id is in list_of_row_objects`

Comment: Here is one way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870760/filtering-a-pyspark-dataframe-with-sql-like-in-clause

Comment: @KarthikRavindra thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

The main question is how big is list_of_row_objects. If it is small then the link provided by @Karthik Ravindra

If it is big, then you can instead use dataframe_of_row_objects. do an inner join between your dataframe and dataframe_of_row_objects with the artist column in dataframe_of_row_objects and the id column in your original dataframe. This would basically remove any id not in dataframe_of_row_objects.

Of course using a join is slower but it is more flexible. For lists which are not small but are still small enough to fit into memory you can use the broadcast hint to still get better performance.