# Filtering a hive dataset based on a python list

Tags: python, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm pretty new to hive and spark, but what I want to do feels like it should be simple. Essentially, I want to take a list from Python and then only pull in records from hive that have a key in that list. Like this:

```
my_list=['a','b','c','d']
new_dataset = 
    spark.sql(
    select * 
    from hive_dataset 
    where variable_name in my_list)
```

I would even be fine with handling it after the sql statement. Like this:

```
my_list=['a','b','c','d']
new_dataset = 
    spark.sql(
    select * 
    from hive_dataset)

new_dataset=new_dataset(new_dataset[variable_name] in my_list)
```

I know this is a pretty generic question, but how would I do this? Is this even possible?

Comment: For the second method you can use `isin`: `new_dataset=new_dataset.where(new_dataset[variable_name].isin(my_list))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering a Pyspark DataFrame with SQL-like IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870760/filtering-a-pyspark-dataframe-with-sql-like-in-clause)

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkPredicatePushdown.html makes good reading

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55288734/how-to-get-strings-separated-by-commas-from-a-list-to-a-query-in-pyspark/55335115#55335115

I have updated my response there for DF and sql based approach.

Answer (score 1):

This should work -

```
my_list=['a','b','c','d']

your_filter  = ','.join(["'" +i + "'" for i in my_list])

new_dataset  = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM hive_dataset WHERE variable_name IN ({})".format(your_filter))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just convert to tuple

```
my_list=['a','b','c','d']

new_dataset  = spark.sql(f"""SELECT * 
                               FROM hive_dataset 
                              WHERE variable_name IN {tuple(my_list)}
                          """)
```