# How to get strings separated by commas from a list to a query in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to generate a query by using a list in PySpark

```
list = ["hi@gmail.com", "goodbye@gmail.com"]
query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE email IN (" + list + ")"
```

This is my desired output:

```
query
SELECT * FROM table WHERE email IN ("hi@gmail.com", "goodbye@gmail.com")
```

Instead I'm getting: `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects`

Can anyone help me achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone's having the same issue, I found that you can use the following code:

```
"'"+"','".join(map(str, emails))+"'"
```

and you will have the following output:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE email IN ('hi@gmail.com', 'goodbye@gmail.com')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Dataframe based approach -

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,"hi@gmail.com") ,(2,"goodbye@gmail.com",),(3,"abc@gmail.com",),(4,"xyz@gmail.com")], ['id','email_id'])

email_filter_list = ["hi@gmail.com", "goodbye@gmail.com"]

df.where(col('email_id').isin(email_filter_list)).show()
```

Spark SQL based approach -

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,"hi@gmail.com") ,(2,"goodbye@gmail.com",),(3,"abc@gmail.com",),(4,"xyz@gmail.com")], ['id','email_id'])
df.createOrReplaceTempView('t1')

sql_filter  = ','.join(["'" +i + "'" for i in email_filter_list])

spark.sql("SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE email_id IN ({})".format(sql_filter)).show()
```