# How do I use Boolean logic within a pyspark dataframe for sets

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a new column in a pyspark dataframe that is predicated on the contents of another column. The other column has all integers, and I want the new column to be encoded with either 1's or 0's.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df2 = df2.withColumn('Industrial', F.when(F.col('CODE') in (1,2,3,4), 1).otherwise(0))
```

This doesn't work since it wants just Boolean logic. Is there a work around for this?

EDIT: Could still be useful for others since it creates a new column and does a little more than just a check of isin().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering a Pyspark DataFrame with SQL-like IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870760/filtering-a-pyspark-dataframe-with-sql-like-in-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `col.isin` method

```
df2 = df2.withColumn('Industrial', F.when(F.col('CODE').isin((1,2,3,4)), 1).otherwise(0))
```