# How to query a column by multiple values in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I got a dataframe through `spark.read.csv()` in pyspark. I can filter data by using `df.filter(df['mobile'] == 'Vivo')`. Now, I want to filter 'mobile' column by multiple values.

For example, I have a `band_list=['Apple','Samsung','Vivo']`,

I want to filter `'mobile'` value in this band_list.

I know one way is `df.filter((df['mobile'] == 'Apple') | (df['mobile'] == 'Samsung')|(df['mobile'] == 'Vivo'))`, but it is not flexible.

Can somebody tell me another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyspark dataframe filter or include based on list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421845/pyspark-dataframe-filter-or-include-based-on-list). Also [Filtering a Pyspark DataFrame with SQL-like IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870760/filtering-a-pyspark-dataframe-with-sql-like-in-clause/41287797)

Answer (score 6):

you can use [isin](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/column.html#Column.isin):

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(['abc123','Apple','Samsung','ZXC321','Vivo'],"string")
band_list=['Apple','Samsung','Vivo']
df.filter(df.value.isin(band_list)).show()

+-------+
|  value|
+-------+
|  Apple|
|Samsung|
|   Vivo|
+-------+
```

Comment: Good one without unnecessary explicit call to RDD

Comment: is it `inplace` operation?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df1 = spark.createDataFrame([('spark',),('scala',),('elixir',)],['lang'])
>>> df1.show()
+------+
|  lang|
+------+
| spark|
| scala|
|elixir|
+------+

>>> df1.where('''lang in ('spark','scala')''').show()
+-----+
| lang|
+-----+
|spark|
|scala|
+-----+
```