# How to pass dataframe to pyspark parallel operation?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to filter the data frame by values of salary then saving them as CSV files using pyspark.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()
data = [('James','M',30),('Anna','F',41),
  ('Robert','M',62),('yana','M',30) 
]
columns = ["firstname","gender","salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = columns)
df.show()
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([30,41,62]).foreach(lambda x : df.filter(df.salary == x).show())
```

while running this code it returns

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object
```

(EDITED)

More I need to perform a file write concurrently spark filters the data frame

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([30,41,62]).foreach(lambda x : df.filter(df.salary == x).write.save((f'/path-to-drive-location/{driver}'))
```

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870760/filtering-a-pyspark-dataframe-with-sql-like-in-clause for same

Comment: Why use foreach?

Comment: Instead of using `foreach` use `isin` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421845/pyspark-dataframe-filter-or-include-based-on-list)

Comment: @yogeshgarud I need the data to be filtered on the basis of salary 

df1
-----
james  M  30
yana    M  30

df2
--------------
Anna F 41

df3
------------
Rober M 62

like the above data frames, I need to split them and salary should be passed as iterators to each worker node of a fully parallelized operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to deal with RDD and `foreach` or `map`. You can just create another dataframe and perform an inner join (or any other join you want).

```py
salaries = [30, 41, 62]

a = spark.createDataFrame([(s,) for s in salaries], ['salary'])
+------+
|salary|
+------+
|    30|
|    41|
|    62|
+------+

df2 = df.join(a, on=['salary'])
df2.show()
+------+---------+------+
|salary|firstname|gender|
+------+---------+------+
|    30|    James|     M|
|    30|     yana|     M|
|    41|     Anna|     F|
|    62|   Robert|     M|
+------+---------+------+

df2.write.csv('/path/to/location')
```

Comment: great work ....